# Adding a concern to the controller causes AbstractController::ActionNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I use the same `set_modpack` method in several controllers, and I decided to make a concern for it. But when I add the concern to the controller, all routes give me `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` error.

My routes:

```rb
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end
resources :modpacks, concerns: :commentable do
  resources :releases, controller: 'modpack_releases'
end
```

My concern:

```rb
# app/controllers/concerns/modpack_derivative.rb
module ModpackDerivative
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  protected
    def set_modpack
      @modpack = Modpack.find(params[:id])
      if @modpack.nil?
        @modpack = Modpack.find_by!(slug: params[:id])
      end
    end
end
```

My controller:

```rb
# app/controllers/modpacks_controllers.rb
class ModpacksController < ApplicationController
  include ModpackDerivative

  before_action :set_modpack, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # 100% standard index, create, show, 
  # update and destroy actions (API)

  private
    def modpack_params
      params.require(:modpack).permit(:logo, :name, :slug, :summary, :tags, :description)
    end
end
```

It works fine if I delete the concern and paste the `set_modpack` methods inside the controllers.

Comment: Can you add the names of the files? Rails is [convention-over-configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) so the names of the files might make a difference.

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't the set_modpack method be public?

Comment: My file names are controllers/modpack_controller and controllers/concerns/modpack_derivative

Comment: Tried making it public, no difference

Comment: What if you move the before action into the module inside a included do block?

Comment: @Hackman nothing changes. Also, I need it to be different inside different controllers using the concern

Comment: You should consider using `Modpack.find_by!("id = :id OR slug = :id", id: params[:id])` which will do a single query instead of two (worst case).

Comment: I also believe that `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` is raised when rails can't find a public method in the controller that corresponds to the route. Thus its probably not related to your concern that provides private methods used in a callback.

Comment: Good point on `find_by!`, but I don’t understand why can’t Rails resolve a method only when concern is included, given that all methods are public and work excellent without the concern included